# SQL 2005 query with dynamic table generation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a problem and I'm not sure of the best way to solve it or the most efficient way to handle it. I need to query a database that contains supervisors and employees but I need to be able to go down as many levels as the user asks for. By that I mean, the query will take in two primary params, the originating employee and how many levels to search through. The query will start with looking for all employees that report to the originating employee and return a list of these employees. This would be a level 1 search. If the user passes through the value 2, then I would need to get all the employees who report to all the employees that were selected in the first list. If the user passes the value 3, then I would get not only the first level employees, then second, but then I would get all the employees that report to the employees listed in second query. In my mind I would have to create a new table for each one of these queries then in the end combine the results to be returned as one table. Is that the correct approach? If so, what's the best way to create then clean up these tables?

The table being searched is a pretty simple structure:

```
ID       EmployeeId       Supervisor
---      ----------       ----------
1        Harlow, Bill     Foster, Sam
2        Foster, Sam      Jenkins, Alex
3        Jenkins, Alex    Wadley, Mike
```

The first query itself is pretty simple:

```
select Id from dbo.Employees where Supervisor = 'Foster, Sam'
```

Comment: Read [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Here is the 2005 CTE direct reference for the article Remus posted above: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.90).aspx